# is there a resurrect-able singleton design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, singleton

we have to control some hardware, due to driver's limitation all calls shall comes from the same caller object, so i implemented as singleton pattern.

the driver might hang, in this case it has to be killed and the application shall try to initiate it again... so i modified the singleton as resurrect-able - sorry i just coined this term as i don't know what's the correct one.
basically its life style is like this:
not exist => singleton #1 => hang => killed => singleton #2 ...

during code review my colleague said he never seen such singleton before, as he understands a singleton is THE only one during whole application lifetime....

is there such a "resurrect-able singleton" design pattern? is there some pitfalls i shall be aware?

oh i'm using C#, though i take this more a general OO design topic...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singleton pattern doesn't really apply here, since you said yourself more objects need to be created.

I would suggest you use something similar to a factory pattern instead:

- call factory.get()
- if no objects exist, create a new object
- if an object exists and is valid, return it
- if an object exists and is hanging, kill it and create a new object

You implement a factory such that there is only one object created at a time.

Comment: Sounds like a hybrid of factory and singleton, really only using the factory pattern to wrap access to the singleton as I was getting at. +1 anyway

Comment: @Yuck it seems so, I know, but conceptually it's different. Singleton only allows one instance, whereas this allows multiple instances, albeit at different times.

Comment: hmmm, never mind. so it's good to use the term factory, to avoid a conceptual confusion. ok, i'll do that :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Still, a Factory is supposed to be a static object used to construct instances as needed. It is not designed to limit the number of concurrent instances in a process. Singleton, however, does just that. I don't think it's worth arguing semantics here (and IMHO this is the problem with design patterns...) but I will maintain that your pattern is a factory / singleton hybrid.

Comment: The Singleton pattern normally only checks to see if an instance exists and if so, returns that, if not, it instantiates a new object. In that scenario there's nothing that precludes the destroying of the current instance and a new instance being created. In essence, Singleton is more "one at a time" than "one only, ever".